# MySQL: How to perform case-insensitive query

Tags: mysql

As far as I know LIKE operator should be case insensitive, but if I have the string "ABC Software" and I get the following query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ... LIKE 'AbC Softwa%'
```

I get a zero-rows result set (If I upper-case the second letter, the b, I get the right result). Why? Previously I had *utf8_bin* as character encoding, so I switch to *latin_swedish_ci*, supposing that binary matching was the source of all errors, but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is case-insensitive by default.

If you want to perform a case-**sensitive** search use:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ... LIKE BINARY 'AbC Softwa%'
```

If your database, or table is configured to be case-sensitive by default, then to perform a case-**insensitive** search, you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ... COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci LIKE 'AbC Softwa%' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

If you are using utf8, then try this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ... COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE 'AbC Softwa%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

You might want to investigate why your database is case-sensitive.

To see how the server is configured, run:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';
```

To see the collation of your tables, run:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

And to see the default collation for the database:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

where `dbname` is the name of the database.

Comment: No, I want perform a case-insensitive match, but MySQL performs by default a case-sensitive one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE UPPER(...) LIKE 'ABC SOFTWA%'
```